# PHP image upload is working on localhost but not working on server

Tags: php, mysql, forms, image, image-uploading

Image Upload working fine in localhost but it is not working in live server.HTML form shows success message after submitting the form but no data is stored in the database.I have tried to print error but there is no error. My Code :

```
    <?php
include './login_validity.php';

$res = '';
$mes = '';
$img = NULL;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['title'];
    $des = $_POST['description'];
    $shrt_detail = $_POST['shrt_description'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $show_status = $_POST['is_show'];
    $detail = $des;


    //------------------image upload---------------------
    if (!empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])) {

      $target_dir = "uploads/";
      $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

      $uploadOk = 1;
      $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

       $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
       if ($check !== false) {
              $uploadOk = 1;
       } else {
              $_SESSION['message'] = "File is not an image.";
              $uploadOk = 0;
       }


      // Allow certain file formats
       if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "tif") 
       {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
       }
      // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
       if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
       // if everything is ok, try to upload file
       } else {
         if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "The file " . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";

         } else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
         }
      }
      $img = $target_file;
     }

    $query = "INSERT INTO slider (title,image,shrt_description,description,date,is_show) VALUES ('$name','$img','$shrt_detail','$detail','$date','$show_status')";
    $res = $conn->query($query); 
    $mes = "Successfully Added";
}
?>
```

After submitting the form I have checked the uploads folder in server.I found the uploaded file on that folder. But when I checked phpMyadmin no data in database about that uploaded file. But when I run this page in localhost then everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is here:

```
$res = '';
$mes = '';
$img = NULL;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['title'];
    $des = $_POST['description'];
    $shrt_detail = $_POST['shrt_description'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $show_status = $_POST['is_show'];
    $detail = $des;
```

You have to change it to:

```
$res = '';
$mes = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['title'];
    $des = $_POST['description'];
    $shrt_detail = $_POST['shrt_description'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $show_status = $_POST['is_show'];
    $detail = $des;
    $img = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
```

If you do `$img = NULL;` your not receiving it.
You have to do `$img = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];` in order to get the submitted data from the form

P.S - Where are you declaring the variable `$conn`? I think you have to include your connection in that document, otherwise it won't send the data to your database.

Comment: You have sql injection vulnerabilities. Use prepared statements. Don’t accept raw $_POST data. Also, you are inserting literals in your query. ‘$name’ should be escaped using ‘“.$name.”’